# What is the purpose or why is ActionView::TestCase or similar modules inherited in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, tdd

in the railstutorial.org listing 5.36 why is ApplicationHelperTest inherited from ActionView::TestCase , as  it is only a test for a helper .

```
require 'test_helper'

class ApplicationHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
 test "full title helper" do
 assert_equal full_title,         FILL_IN
 assert_equal full_title("Help"), FILL_IN
end
```

end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails, a "Helper" is a module full of methods that are used in Views... thus tests that test Helper methods need to be able to render views in order to access and test those methods

Comment: I tried inheriting `ActionController::TestCase` and the test case worked , does it mean that helpers are available to controllers as well.

Comment: helpers aren't available to controllers, but views get rendered in controller-tests (if you let em), so they're probably available in controller-tests